# SQL: How can I make this query more flexible

Tags: sql

Persons (table **Person**) passed exams with marks (table **Exam**) for several disciplines (table **Discipline**).
I have to fetch table [person/discipline] with mark values in cells.

How can I create a more flexible query than this:

```
SELECT 
  p.*,  -- persons 
  ae.*, -- "A" exam mark 
  be.*, -- "B" exam mark 
  ...

FROM 
  Person p,
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Exam ae ON (p.Id = ae.PersonId and ae.DisciplineId = 1)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Exam be ON (p.Id = be.PersonId and be.DisciplineId = 2)
  ...
```

?

I want it to work for an arbitrary range of disciplines.

Comment: Are you saying you want it to work for an arbitrary range of disciplines?

Comment: @Blorgbeard - yes, that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by flexible?  You will need to provide some more information on what you want.

At a guess something like the following might give you what you want, although if you provide more information on the table structures we could tell for sure what you want to do.

```
SELECT 
  p.*,  -- persons 
  (CASE When ae.DisciplineID = 1 THEN ae.Mark ELSE null END) as 'A_Mark',
  (CASE When ae.DisciplineID = 2 THEN ae.Mark ELSE null END) as 'B_Mark',
  ...
FROM 
  Person p,
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Exam ae ON (p.Id = ae.PersonId)
ORDER BY p.Id, ae.DisciplineId
```

Comment: `ELSE null` is redundant - if no when clause matches, and there's no else clause, the value of a CASE expression is NULL.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I left it in to better illustrate what was happening.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but may it be refactored to work without knowledge of concrete DisciplineId ? Let Discipline table be joined for Discipline.Title

Comment: @Andrew - So you want the query to return a different number of columns depending on how many exams the person has taken or result they achieved?  You could do that using dynamic sql but that would be using the wrong tool for the job.  Its better to return a set number of columns from the query and use your application/excel/website to control how the data is shown.  What you want can be achieved in Excel using a pivot table much more easily that writing complicated SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You could group by person, and select the appropriate mark using a case:

```
SELECT  p.Name
,       min(case when e.DisciplineId = 1 then e.Mark end) as Exam_A_Mark
,       max(case when e.DisciplineId = 2 then e.Mark end) as Exam_B_Mark
FROM    Person p
LEFT JOIN 
        Exam e 
ON      p.Id = e.PersonId
GROUP BY
        p.Id
,       p.Name
```

Note that the proper SQL approach would be to return one row per exam to the client, and let the client format the result by "pivoting" one row per exam into one column per exam.

Comment: Nice answer :)  Same route i took.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but may it be refactored to work without knowledge of concrete DisciplineId ? Let Discipline table be joined for Discipline.Title

Comment: @Andrew Florko: AFAIK you cannot pivot an arbitrary number of columns.  There are some database specific solutions using dynamic SQL, but all database vendors seem to agree that it's a really bad idea.

Comment: You probably meant to put each CASE into `MAX()` or whatever aggregate you prefer in such... er... cases.